# How to set select option to list value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    getListCalender = document.getElementById('CalenderListDrop').value;
    spHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    parentContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, spHostUrl);
    web = parentContext.get_web();

    var allLists = web.get_lists();

    context.load(allLists);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
            function() {

                var listEnumerator = allLists.getEnumerator();
                while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var listName = listEnumerator.get_current();
                    var listTypeId = listName.get_baseTemplate();

                    if (listTypeId == SP.ListTemplateType.events) {


                        alert(listName.get_title());
                    }     

                }

            }),
        function(sender, args) {
            alert(args.get_message());

        }
}
```

);

I am using `getListCalender = document.getElementById('CalenderListDrop').value;`

To call on my control in default.aspx , how could i then call on this control and set listName.get_Title()`<select id="CalenderListDrop">

      <option></option>
</select>`

Comment: @Vadim Gremyachev

Answer (score 1):

Inside the while loop you can use

```
$('#CalendarListDrop').append("<option>" + listName.get_Title() + "</option>");
```

Comment: Alright i made it work like this, 
                            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                             
                                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                                getListCalender.options.add(opt);
                                opt.text = array[i];